# Recording audio possible with tvOS?

Tags: audio, avfoundation, audio-recording, microphone, tvos

I have an iOS app that I would like to port to tvOS.  However, the app requires that the user to speak into a microphone and record their voice.  I was hoping to use the microphone on the remote control.  The current iOS app uses AVAudioRecorder to record the user's voice.  However, I looked at the AVFoundation API and it appears that AVAudioRecorder is not available in tvOS.

Is there another API or workaround for this, or am I just out of luck?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to this post on the developer forums, it appears that using the Siri Remote microphone is not currently available:

> No, there's no API to access to the microphone.

https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/16926

Comment: I submitted an new feature request to Apple's bug reporter, asking them to provide an API to access the microphone.  Hopefully, access to the microphone will appear in a future version of the tvOS API.

Comment: @DavidSwan Do you have a link to the request that we can upvote? Any response from Apple so far?